# ajax collaps panel not working in my application?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

i am going to implement the collapsiblepane in my application but it is not getting any thing just two link buttons

this is my code

```
CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="CollapsiblePanelExtender1"
        AutoCollapse ="False" AutoExpand ="false" ScrollContents ="true" TargetControlID ="mypanel"
         Collapsed ="true" CollapsedSize ="0" ExpandedSize ="300"
         ExpandControlID ="mylink" CollapseControlID ="mylink2"  
         CollapsedText ="Show Details..." ExpandedText ="Hide Details..."   runat="server">
        </cc1:CollapsiblePanelExtender> 



    <asp:Panel ID ="mypanel" runat ="Server" Visible ="False"  >
       <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat ="server" ></asp:TextBox><br />
       <asp:Button ID="btn" runat ="Server" Text ="Click" />           
     </asp:Panel>  
     <asp:LinkButton ID="mylink" runat ="Server" Text ="Mydetaails" OnClick="mylink_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="mylink2" runat ="Server" Text ="HideMydetails" OnClick="mylink2_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: please edit to display code of collapse panel itself

Comment: i place that code but it is not displaying Mr. Dewfy

Comment: ya check out Mr.Dewfy i place the collapsible panel extender

Comment: Make sure, that there are at least 4 space before code you place. It is formating rule of stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but can see at least 2 problems:

1. You server tag of CollapsiblePanelExtender must be closed, so you have:

   runat="server">

but it must be:

```
runat="server"/>
```

2. Did you recreate CSS classes? CollapsiblePanelExtender works by manipulating styles, so these styles must be present. Also look at note from ( http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/CollapsiblePanel/CollapsiblePanel.aspx ) *"Note: CollapsiblePanel assumes that the standard CSS box model is being used ... so please use the !DOCTYPE declaration (as found at the top of this page and enabled by default for new ASP.NET pages) to specify that the page should be rendered in IE's standards-compliant mode."*

Comment: same problem Mr.Dewfy i change runat="Server" but not use

Comment: @Surya sasidhar - the problem not in case of Server, you forget slash '/' in ending of tag.
Also please see if you have correct CSS classes